# Javascript check if array contains value

Tags: javascript

I have a array with numbers `ListIds` and i like to check if it contains my user id `myId` but for some strange reason it keeps on returning `no match` what I'm i doing wrong here?

```
      var ListIds = object.ListFolowers; // = 33,34,35
      var myId = userProfileID2_class; // = 33

      if(ListIds.indexOf(myId)>=0){
      debug_log('Value exist');
      } else {
      debug_log('no match');
      }
```

ps if i change `if(ListIds.indexOf(myId)>=0)` to `if(ListIds.indexOf(33)>=0)` it works...

fixit it by adding a `+` to `if(ListIds.indexOf(+myId)>=0){`

Comment: Don't know because you've not given us any actual data, but a guess would be that you're comparing strings to numbers, which won't work with `.indexOf()`. Try adding `+` before `myId` when you pass it to `indexOf()`.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/xpn7c2wx/). If `indexOf(33)` works but `indexOf(myId)` doesn't, it clearly means `myId` is not `33`. Check `myId === 33` and you will see.

Comment: Code looks correct to me. Is `ListIds` actually an array of numbers and what is `myId`?

Comment: @squint the + works thanks

Comment: Check your data types. You probably have somewhere it is `string` and somewhere it is `int`

Comment: Just curious. What is the output of `console.log(myId)`? I don't understand the fix. Care to explain why?

Comment: @SamuelToh `debug_log(myId)` gives me `LOG: 33`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rohit Shedage's guess was correct.

Your problem here is that `userProfileID2_class` is a string value and by doing `+myId` to the string type, the javascript engine would have automatically converted the string to an integer before applying `indexOf` to it.

You might want to consider fixing the root problem cause instead. That is, storing your Id as an integer/ converting it to integer before setting it.